# How do I enter the Euro Symbol €

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to use a shortcut in order to enter the Euro symbol:  <kbd>€</kbd> like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in windows.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy! Just press the right Alt and the "E" key.

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

Comment: Very thank you! I traveled the world to find that...

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold compose key (see Keyboard settings), press <kbd>c</kbd> and then <kbd>=</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Jeroen said, its depends on keyboard layout. The best way that works with all the keyboards is to use *UNICODE*.

Every known character has its own unicode number. In Linux, you can write it holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> and typing the key <kbd>U</kbd> followed by the unicode number.

In this case, `€` is known with unicode `U20AC`
 So press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then <kbd>2</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, to confirm <kbd>space</kbd>

More info about Unicode numbers: [Unicode characters](https://unicode-table.com/en)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the keyboard layout you're using.

"US International with dead keys" for example uses <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>, while "US alternative international" uses <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>.

Other layouts might have other shortcuts.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> does not work on Kubuntu (British), but it is there. It just needs turning on.

Kubuntu settings manager 5.10.5

1. ->Settings
2. ->Input Devices
3. ->Keyboard
4. ->Advanced
5. ->Adding currency signs to certain keys.

I added <kbd>€</kbd> to <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as that option did not conflict with the use of any other symbols.